# How to decide between additive vs. multiplicative logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, model

I want to collect data in an experiment where I manipulate two treatment factors. Factor A has two possible nominal values, Factor B has three possible nominal values. The outcome is binary.

Therefore, I have six treatment groups. I assume that there is a multiplicative connection of my two factors because of the experimental setting.
I want to generate an logistic regression model and test the impact of the factors.

Although I do not treat independently with these factors: Is it useful or allowed to generate an additional additive model and compare both models to maybe find out that the additional model is more appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

Am I correct in interpreting the question as whether it's possible to test whether a model with an interaction between the factors fits better than a model without one? If so, yes, a straightforward way to do this would be to fit a model with the interaction (i.e., `y ~ F1 + F2 + F1:F2`) and one without (i.e., `y ~ F1 + F2`) and perform a likelihood ratio test for the two models. A significant p-value for this test indicates that the interaction is (statistically) important (i.e., that including the interaction yields a model that fits the data better).

Comment: What if I want to compare more than two models? Do I test every single one against the reduced-model (β_1=β_2=0) and take the one with the lowest AIC if all models are significant or is there some better approach?
Is it reasonable to take the simple addiditve model (like y~F1+F2) if it is significant compared to the reduced model because it is easier to interpret? Or should I strive for "the best" model (however this is accomplished)